# Binomial Proportions when sampling without replacement not studied?

Tags: binomial-distribution, hypergeometric-distribution, finite-population, bernoulli-process

#### Question

When doing surveys with a population, we obviously don't replace by design. Why is it then that the mathematics and statistics described in textbooks seems to be veering more on the side of sampling with replacement than without?

#### Background

I want to determine the equivalence of doing n-Bernoulli trials with choosing stones from a bag with and without replacement.

Let $p < 1$.

#### Scenarios

**Scenario 1:** Let's say we have 4 coin tosses and each toss has probability $p$ of heads. Record the number of heads.

**Scenario 2:** Let's say we have a bag with $p$ proportion of red stones. Suppose each stone is can be chosen with equal probability, and you select one stone, determine if it's red, then replace the stone. After doing this 4 times, you record the number of red stones.

**Scenario 3:** Let's say we have the same set up as in the previous problem but we are sampling without replacement.

It seems to me that the first two scenarios are equivalent, and that the last one is slightly off, depending on the number of stones in the bag. The more stones, the more similar the probability distribution of Scenario 3 looks to the other two scenarios.

Comment: (1) If the population is very large by comparison to the sample, there is very little difference between with and without replacement, and with replacement is simpler. (2) Google "finite population sampling" and you may find that a substantial amount of research has been done on sampling without replacement. (Whether it's found its way into undergraduate textbooks is another question.)

Comment: When doing finite population sampling, you no longer do with binomial distributions, but hypergeometric. So you could change title to hypergeometric proportions.